# MySQL update statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a the row in the table `'notes'` using the following queries in PHP.

```
    $xyz = mysql_query("Select AVG(x) as AVG_X, AVG(y) as AVG_Y, AVG(z) as AVG_Z FROM  `notes_two` where id=".$id);//I am selecting average value of (x,y,x) from another table notes_two

    $rowxyz = mysql_fetch_row($xyz);

    // Saving the position and z-index of the note:

    mysql_query("UPDATE notes SET xyz='".$rowxyz[0]."x".$rowxyz[1]."x".$rowxyz[2]."', actualxyz='".$x."x".$y."x".$z."' WHERE id=".$id);
```

It is not getting updated.

Comment: try to debug, in your page print this query,copy it and past it in phpmyadmin , and  test if it's really what you want to do

Comment: AH the average of co-ordinates from last night ?? Echo the query to see if data is coming through. Or use mysql_error() to see whats going on.

Comment: are you sure it's $rowxyz['0'] and not $rowxyz[0] ...etc?

Comment: use this  `mysql_query("UPDATE....") or die(mysql_error());` and post your error.

Comment: I am updating it via AJAX call. So I am not able to figure exactly what is happening

Comment: @Venky, you should try this:`mysql_query(
"UPDATE notes 
SET xyz='".$rowxyz[0]."x".$rowxyz[1]."x".$rowxyz[2]."',
actualxyz='".$x."x".$y."x".$z."' 
WHERE id='".$id"'
");` you should mention this format  WHERE id=' ".$id"  '

Answer (score -1):

for starters use sprintf when you are working with loads of variables, or better yet pass them as attributes to mysql. Then just copy your generated sql into phpmyadmin or what other tool your using and sql will provide you with debug info so you can easely see your mistake.

good luck

Comment: that's what i told him in the first comment

Comment: Using `sprintf` versus concatenation versus interpolation is a style choice, it shouldn't affect whether the query works. This doesn't seem like answer, it should be posted as a comment (I know, you don't have enough rep to comment -- that doesn't mean you should post a non-answer as an answer).

Comment: true... but copying it into an sql client to see the error is!